# Upper Bound on Relative Entropy

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, entropy

I am currently reading the book "A Dynamical Approach to Random Matrix Theory". The authors introduce the notion of relative entropy and remark that relative entropy is a weaker measure of the distance between probability measures than the $L^p$ distance for any $p>1.$ The following inequality (authors call it 'elementary' and therefore leave the proof as an exercise) is mentioned as a justification for this claim:
$$\int f\log f\;d\mu\le 2\left[\int |f-1|^p\; d\mu\right]^{1/p}+\frac{2}{p-1}\int |f-1|^p\; d\mu,$$
where $f\;d\mu$ and $\mu$ are a probability measure.

I have no idea how to get this inequality. I thought of using
$$\int f\log f\;d\mu= \int (f-1)\log f\;d\mu+ \int \log f\;d\mu,$$
and then apply Hölder's inequality to the first part but it doesn't seem to give me what I want. Any hint/help is appreciated.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Why did you remove the [tag:inequality] tag? The tag summary says "Questions on proving, manipulating and applying inequalities. Do not use this tag just because an inequality appears somewhere in your question." That seems applicable here?

Comment: @joriki: feel free to add it. To me most interesting problems are about inequalities, being in analysis, probability or geometry and the tag inequality seems redundant. Also, I made a minor  edit to make the problem put it once more under the radar.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: OK. You succeeded in putting it on the radar, causing me in turn to make a small edit to fix a typo :-)